# Spring boot JPA function with In and Contains

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I want to create a jpa function passing it a list of strings and looking for a column to contain it, it would be like joining these two functions.

```
findByNameIn(strList);
findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you need to create a @Service that receive a Collection of Strings and call those two methods. I suggest you to use CompletableFuture and call those methods in parallel.

Comment: the problem is that I want to use it with Spring Pageable, so I need it to be in a single function

Comment: You can create a jpql using @query annotation like
@query("select e from Your entity e where ....) Page<obj>. Findby (collection, string)